# How to understand NonNullable in typescript?

Tags: typescript

In TS, NonNullable is defined as

```
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T
```

One example,

```
type T0 = NonNullable<string | number | undefined>;
```

After evaluation, **T0** becomes

```
type T0 = string | number
```

So how does TS infer **T0**? I thought it returns **never** in this case, since **string | number | undefined** extends **null | undefined** (correct?). But how can this be **string | number** ?

Related to this, why does TS not use the following definition?

```
type NonNullable<T> = Exclude<T, null | undefined>
```

Answer (score 1):

> So how does TS infer T0? I thought it returns never in this case, since string | number | undefined extends null | undefined (correct?). But how can this be string | number ?

If you check the documentation about the [`NonNullable<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) you will see that *NonNullable*:

> Constructs a type by excluding null and undefined from Type.

So in your example

```js
type T0 = NonNullable<string | number | undefined>;
```

the type `string | number | undefined` for *NonNullable* is not viewed as an entire type by itself, it is a type conformed by the types `string` or `number` or `undefined` and since the type `undefined` will be excluded by *NonNullable*, the final type results in `string | number`.

> why does TS not use the following definition?

Yes, they are the same <strike>but one of the reasons could be that they want to build the **[Utility Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)** from scratch and not to use a composed type. If you see the definition for *NonNullable*, you can see what is doing under the hood almost directly instead of going to the definition of *Exclude* to see the entire functionality.</strike> I just noticed that there are some Utility types conformed by another Utility types. It could be for readability reasons, beacuse if you see the [relase notes for version 2.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html), the type *NonNullable* was defined by using *Diff* first.

```
type NonNullable<T> = Diff<T, null | undefined>;
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but regarding the first question, I know the behavior of NonNullable, but not sure how TS infers that, per your statement "since the type undefined will be excluded by NonNullable", could you elaborate how TS excludes it from typings?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a union like `string | number | never`, `never` will be automatically removed from it.

So, let's imagine you have the following type: `string | number | null`.

Let's pass it to `type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T`

`T`, being `string | number | null`, will split the expression `T extends null | undefined ? never : T` into a union of three members, where `string`, `number`, and `null` will replace `T` correspondingly, i.e. `string extends ... : never : string | number extends ... : never : number | null extends ... : never : null`.
The first two expressions will return `string` and `number`. The last one will return `never`.
In result, we have a type `string | number | never`, where `never` will be immediately removed by typescript

You can read more about it here, https://www.zhenghao.io/posts/ts-never#filter-out-union-members-from-union-types

Comment: Would you say its the same ideia with `undefined` values? in case its NonNullable, i want it to be either false or true, with no undefined values.

like:

`NonNullable<boolean | undefined>`